# Nesting INDIRECT in MAX function

Tags: excel, tabs, excel-indirect

Please let me know if I need to clarify.. but I will try to boil this down to make it as simple as possible.

I have a workbook with 51 tabs. Tab 1 is a summary table while tabs 2-51 is made up of a column of data C2:C6. (Identical column but different data in each tab).

The summary tab contains 2 columns. A "Name" column and a results column, where the "Name" column lists each data tab by name (ie tabs 2-51).

I want the results column to pull the Max from the column in tabs 2-51. I could write =MAX(TAB2!C$2:C$6), but I want to build this expression to use the Name column to reference each tab, instead of manually inputting Tab2!, TAB3!, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming your Name column is Column A and starting in A2.  In B2 put `=MAX(INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!C$2:C$6)"))`  And copy down

Comment: Hmm.. I am getting an Invalid cell reference error. The above function will use the string in cell A2 (ie the tab name) to reference the tab correct?

Comment: Sorry had an extra `)`.  `=MAX(INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!C$2:C$6"))`

Comment: PERFECT! thanks. Can't select your response as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=MAX(INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!C$2:C$6")) -Scott Craner